# How to set pdf zoom level is 100% using knp snappy -symfony2

Tags: symfony

I'm using KnpSnappyBundle for my Symfony project and I'm trying to define some options for zoom level. for example:

```
return new Response(
                    $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf')->getOutputFromHtml($htmltemplate),
                    200,
                    array(
                        'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
                        'Content-Disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="'.$pdfname.'.pdf"'
                    )
                );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set any option via method `setOption`:

```
$pdfGenerator = $this->get('knp_snappy.pdf');
$pdfGenerator->setOption('zoom', 1);

return new Response(
    $pdfGenerator->getOutputFromHtml($htmltemplate),
    200,
    array(
        'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition'   => 'attachment; filename="'.$pdfname.'.pdf"'
    )
);
```